# Different dates Oracle 11g with TOAD

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, toad

I have the following queries:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949'))) FROM DUAL;  
/*this returns 2/1/2049. */

SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949'),'dd-MON-yyyy')) FROM DUAL; 
/*this returns 2/1/1949.*/
```

Why does the first one returns the year `2049` instead of `1949`?

By Googling I have found that I can "force" the client date format to be the one desire by changing the `key`on the registry:

```
KEY_OraClient11g_home1
NLS_DATE_FORMAT : YYYY/MM/DD
```

Comment: Is the NLS_DATE_FORMAT shown in your question the one which produced the 1949 result?

Comment: No, I added the key and I'm still getting the same results

Comment: With an NLS_DATE_FORMAT of 'YYYY/MM/DD' I'd expect you'd get a date formatted as'2049/02/01'.  Check to see if TOAD has something in its configuration that causes it to format dates using the 'RR' or 'RRRR' year format (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) for docs on TO_CHAR date format models).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing multiple implicit date conversions in both versions. This:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949'))) FROM DUAL;
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949', <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>),
    <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>)) FROM DUAL;
```

whereas the second query has one of those replaced with a specific format. It looks like your default format - which you can set, I believe, in the Toad preferences without modifying the registry directly; it isn't clear if you're even modifying something related to Toad - is `DD-MON-RR`, as shown by plugging that into these queries:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949','DD-MON-RR'),
        'DD-MON-RR'),'DD-MON-RR') AS date1,
    to_date(to_char(to_date('01-FEB-1949','DD-MON-RR'),
        'dd-MON-yyyy'),'DD-MON-RR') AS date2 FROM DUAL;

DATE1                            DATE2
February, 01 2049 00:00:00+0000  February, 01 1949 00:00:00+0000
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11761))

You can see in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11765) that in the first version, the date appears as a string with the year as `49` rather than `1949`, and that is then interpreted - by the `RR` mask - as `2049`, which is the expected behaviour.

Short version: never rely on implicit date conversions or the NLS date format mask.

Comment: Wow, that's some awesome explanation, didn't know that I was doing multiple implicit date conversions. 2nd, I didn't know about `sqlfiddle`. 3rd, I already gave you +1 for all that info, but tomorrow @ the office, I'm gonna check the TOAD config and see how the output for the time is being set.

Comment: @Luis I would ignore the settings in Toad, or any other app, and rely on explicit date format pictures. It's too easy for sifferent apps to have different settings, and then code is not tranportable.

Comment: 'Implicit date conversion' was probably the wrong phrase; that's usually used where there is no `to_date` or `to_char` call, e.g. `where sysdate > '31-May-13'` - which is even worse because it isn't obvious which value will be converted. 'implicit date format mask' is maybe better in this case.